# Use a random generated nr in a list at least twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, html-lists

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/MhhBc/

It contains a with javascript generated lists. Each `<a>` is given a randomly selected class. This random selection is done using:

```
var randomClass;
randomClass = Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 0);
```

This produces a random nr. This nr I use to get a random class defined here:

```
var classes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'];
```

So if the random nr is a `2`, the class will be `b`

This al works perfectly. The problem I have is that I want each class (or random nr) to be used at least twice, before the end of the complete list is reached. (The fiddle has a very short list, the real list is much longer also containing multiple `<ul>`).

Example: so if the random seleted nr is `5` it will give class `e`. This means this nr/class must be used again BUT also must be randomly placed over all the different lists. A nr/class can be used multiple times if the random nr happens to be `5` again later in the list.

The total amount of `<a>` usedin the entire list is always even.

Another example:
So the classes over 6 `<a>`'s can be: `a, d, a, e, e, d`. All classes are in there twice and all random.

This is wrong: `a, d, b, b, e, c`. This is the current situation and the classes aren't used twice

Hope I explained the problem clearly enough. My english isn't the best :)

Kind regards,

Comment: Make an array with all the class names in it twice, then shuffle the array. Get your class values by stepping through it from the beginning.  You can re-shuffle it each time you reach the end of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit - Replaced previous solution as it wasn't repeating across all `ul` tags**

I have updated your code and it now always adds each class at least twice across all of the `<ul>` tags.

I do need the total number of items beforehand. Currently I have added that count as a constant `totalCount` because I didn't want to iterate through the JSON object twice just to get the total count and I wanted to get the main-code working first.

Maybe the total count can be sent down as part of the JSON object as a separate property in the root of the object?

Either way the total count of items has to be known up-front somehow.

I moved some of the required variables to a more global scope as the render method does get called for each `ul`.

```
var classes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'];
//var classes = ['a', 'd', 'f'];
var sourceClasses = [];
var totalCount = 6;
var selectedClasses = [];

Menu.prototype.render = function() {    
    // Get total item count between all arrays
    //debugger;    
    var ul = $("<ul />");

    $.each(this.data, function(i, e) {
        var li = $("<li />");

        //console.log(listItemCount);
        //debugger;
        $.each(e, function(j, f) {
            //debugger;
            // If we have no more classes left we re-set the list of items to the original source
            // SourceClasses.length will off course not be 0 ever if we already passed the half-way mark.
            if(sourceClasses.length === 0){
                for(index = 0; index < classes.length; index++){
                    sourceClasses.push(classes[index]);
                }
            }            

            var randomClass;
            randomClass = Math.round(Math.random() * (sourceClasses.length - 1) + 0);

            var selectedClass = sourceClasses[randomClass];

            li.append($("<a></a>", {
                href: f.url,
                text: f.title,
                class: selectedClass
            }));

            sourceClasses.splice(sourceClasses.indexOf(selectedClass), 1);
            selectedClasses.push(selectedClass);

            // Check for half-way mark.
            var itemCount = selectedClasses.length;

            if (totalCount % 2 != 0) {
                if (itemCount === (totalCount - 1) / 2) {
                    sourceClasses = selectedClasses;
                    var additionalClass = Math.round(Math.random() * (sourceClasses.length - 1) + 0);
                    sourceClasses.push(sourceClasses[additionalClass]);
                    selectedClasses = [];
                };
            } else {
                if (itemCount === totalCount / 2) {
                    sourceClasses = selectedClasses;
                    selectedClasses = [];
                };
            }
        });
        ul.append(li);
    });

    //console.log($($(ul).find("a")));
    return ul;
};
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MhhBc/24/) - Each class at least used twice across all list items

*(Check the rendered HTML for the results using the debugger tool in your browser)*

You notice that now the first thing happening within the inner loop, I'm checking if there are any available classes left and if there is not I re-set the available classes to the original list.

This will only every happen if your original list of available classes is less than the number of total items.

I'm still removing selected classes from the list of available classes during the iteration of each list item to ensure each class will at least show up twice.

I'm still recording selected classes in another array which I then use to re-set the array of available classes when half-way through the list of items.

The code works if the total number of items is odd or even.

For an even number of total items we simply measure the laf-way marker by dividing by 2.
For an odd number of total items I ensure to mark half-way `(totalCount -1) / 2` and then add a random class to the already selected classes as an additional available class.

This should all work now as expected.....

**Edit (03-Sep-2021)**
I checked the code and there was a logical bug in it. The `itemCount` was re-set after the half-way mark.

This code:

```
var itemCount = selectedClasses.length;
```

Suppose to have been:
    // Moved declaration into the outer scope and steadily increase the count now.
    itemCount += 1

Now the code is doing everything as I planned it to.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MhhBc/30/) - Using 70 links with a class pool of 11

All links get get classes and all classes are used at least twice, seeing we only had 11.
No link should never end up not having a class as there is always a source to choose from.

Regarding your question on making sure every class is used at least ones. That depends on the ratio of available classes to what the half-way mark of the total items are.

If you are using 11 classes as possible source and at least 22 expected links, all your classes are used **and** will be used twice.

If you are using 20 classes and 22 items then **no** not all classes will be used. The reason for that is due to your original requirement `to use each selected class at least twice`.

To ensure all selected classes are used at least twice I'm recording each selection made in a separate array named `selectedClasses`. Ones we have processed half of the possible items I replace the source classes with the selected classes array. Now the other half of the items are only able to select from a list of already selected classes, thus ensuring each class is used at least twice.

Think about it, if you have an array of 20 classes and a total of 22 items you cannot use all classes at least ones if you are at the same time want to ensure each class which has been selected is used at least twice. Those requirements contradict each other.

The number of available classes must be less or equal to half of the total number of items to ensure that all classes are used at least ones **and** all selected classes are used at least twice.

I hope this makes sense but fee if you are stuck feel free to start a chat within the comment section and I can go over the code with you again, no problem.

Comment: Thanks this looks great. A question: if a list has 5 items (which can occur) you say: plus 1 random class three times for odd number of items. This sounds great, but what if another list later on has 7 items? Does the code then uses the one left over from the list with 5 items? So the total keeps even? (7+5= 12 /2 = 6 different items)? Else I can still get classes not used twice. It should span all `<ul>`. If I read the code correctly, it does, but I want to be sure. I'll do some testing myself tomorrow. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Maurice: I didn't realise you wanted the repetitions to span across all `<ul>` tags. I though you only wanted the repetitions per set of `<li>` tags. Let me fix up the code to ensure it treats all `<ul>` tags as a single piece.

Comment: ps: Did some testing. I see at the moment it will use a class twice in each "big" `<li>`, it should do this over the entire lists not just each single `<li>`. Also I see that the first 2 `<li>` have classes d and g, which don't occur later in the lists, so they are not used twice. So something goes wrong here. The goal is that the random class should be done over the entire lists. EDIT: ow I see your comment now, will await your "fix" then, thanks

Comment: @ François Wahl no problem, I am glad you are helping me. Take your time. Thanks

Comment: @Maurice: I replaced my original solution as it was only implementing repetition per set of `<li>` tags rather than the total across all `<ul>` tags. The code should now work as expected. All `<a>` links are treated as one big group now.  The only thing left is how to efficiently determine the total number of items ahead of time. You will need that count up-front. I currently hard-coded it but you could also iterate through the JSON object separately at the start to record the total count. Or send the total count of items along with the JSON as a separate property of the JSON object.

Comment: Thanks a million. The hardcoded part you mean `var totalCount = 6;` right? Thats no problem, I can always let it auto count.

Comment: @Maurice: Yeah, `totalCount` is the one I ment. Glad you can auto count it as I was struggling a bit trying to figure out how to get the count up-front. Hope the rest worked for you now as expected.

Comment: Did some testing, it has some quirks. Example: If I have 66 `<a>` and change `totalCount` to 66, some will not get a class. The lowest nr I can use is 22. Then all get a class (while keeping the 66 `<a>` in it). How come? Also I've discovered that some classes aren't used. I know it's random, but is there a way to get all the classes to be used at least once?

Comment: @Maurice: I fixed a logical bug with the `itemCount`. I also addressed all your questions in the post with an edit. If you are still stuck feel free to add your code to another fiddle and we can start a chat-room from within these comments and I go over the code with you. I'm on-line most evenings anyway. I also added 70 items now in the recent DEMO and left console outputs in it for you to copy-paste into notepad to check that all links have classes and so on. As a general note, don't copy my code verbatim, it should be separated into functions for better maintenance. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again, you really helped me a lot, I appreciate it. I'll do some more testing and let you know. Perhaps a chat is indeed handy, explaining where I need it for and send you some code could help. I'll let you know after some more tests.

Comment: Okay, I think I've corrected the code correctly but I still have class-less ones. Let's have a chat